# window.getMatchedCSSRules on iframe elements/styles

Tags: css, iframe, webkit

Is it possible to use WebKit's window.getMatchedCSSRules on an element in an iframed document to find the matching styles (defined/sourced in the iframed document)?  When I try this out I just get the parent document's matching styles.  Is there another solution?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `window.getMatchedCSSRules`, use `frame.contentWindow.getMatchedCSSRules` on the framed element (e.g. frame may be `$('iframe').get(0)`)